# Failed to install expo-cli on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, expo

I'm trying to create a new React Native application with the expo-cli but I can't install it or run the `init` command on Windows.

With Node v16.16.0 and v16.15.1:

```
> npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\\...
```

With Node v15.13.0 I can install it, but the `expo init` fails:

```
> expo init MyApp
√ Choose a template: » blank (TypeScript)  same as blank but with TypeScript configuration
Error downloading and extracting template package: Error: Could not parse JSON returned from "npm pack expo-template-blank-typescript --dry-run".

expo-template-blank-typescript-45.0.3.tgz

Error: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0
× Something went wrong while downloading and extracting the template.

Can't read JSON file: C:\***\MyApp\app.json
└─ Cause: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\***\MyApp\app.json'
    ├─ readAsync C:\***\v15.13.0\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\json-file\src\JsonFile.ts:158:13
    ├─ extractAndPrepareTemplateAppAsync C:\***\v15.13.0\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\utils\extractTemplateAppAsync.ts:25:25
    └─ actionAsync C:\***\v15.13.0\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\initAsync.ts:287:19
```

How can I use the expo-cli?